# Display Day & Month Names in Indonesian Format on StatusBar

Tags: delphi, date

I am using the following code to show LongDayName, LongMonthName, and Year in my native language, Indonesia, on Borland Delphi 7's StatusBar.

But when I put `FormatDateTime('dddd, dd mmmm yyyy', vDate);` in my statusbar, then I got an error:

```
[Error] Unit1.pas(47): Undeclared identifier: 'vDate'
[Fatal Error] Project1.dpr(5): Could not compile used unit 'Unit1.pas'
```

And when I use `FormatDateTime('dddd, dd mmmm yyyy', Now);` then the result is still in English:

[image: FormatDateTime showing in English]

How do I resolve this to display in Indonesian?

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, ExtCtrls, ComCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    StatusBar1: TStatusBar;
    Timer1: TTimer;
    procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
  private
  public
    function Tanggal(vDate: TDateTime): String;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

 function TForm1.Tanggal(vDate: TDateTime): String;
var
  Counter: byte;
const
  NamaHari : Array [1..7] of string = ('Minggu','Senin','Selasa','Rabu','Kamis','Jumat','Sabtu');
  NamaBulan: Array [1..12] of String = ('Januari','Februari','Maret','April','Mei','Juni','Juli',
  'Agustus','September','Oktober','November','Desember');
begin
  For Counter := 1 to 7 do
  LongDayNames[Counter]:=NamaHari[Counter];
  For Counter := 1 to 12 do
  LongMonthNames[Counter]:=NamaBulan[Counter];
  Result := FormatdateTime('dddd, dd mmmm yyyy', vDate);
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
Statusbar1.Panels[0].Text := FormatDateTime('dddd, dd mmmm yyyy', Now);
end;

end.
```

Comment: Please remove the fake code and replace with the real code. The code that actually fails.

Comment: Not reproducible with your code above. Anyway, when it says that `vDate` is undeclared this is certainly true. Declare a variable, fill it with whatever data you want. Or rewrite that part and change `vDate` to something better.

Comment: The above code taken from this [link](http://delphi.cjcsoft.net/viewthread.php?tid=42782)

Comment: Please show code that demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there.

```
FormatDateTime('dddd, dd mmmm yyyy', vDate);
```

fails with `Undeclared identifier: 'vDate'` because `vDate` doesn't exist - it's the name of a parameter inside the `Tanggal()` method, and so doesn't exist in the `Timer1Timer` method.

Second, you only get English results in `Timer1Timer` because you never call `Tanggal()`, which is what sets the global format settings up and returns the Indonesian-formatted date string.

That is, `Timer1Timer` fires and formats the date according to the global format settings.  It will never use your custom settings, because you haven't set them into the global settings yet.  Working code is:

```
Statusbar1.Panels[0].Text := Tanggal(Now);
```

which passes the result of `Now` into `Tanggal()`, where it is the parameter `vDate`; sets the settings; formats the date using them; returns that string; and sets that string to the status bar panel.

However, you should either not set the format settings every time (do it once on program startup), or you should use a separate `TFormatSettings` variable so you don't overwrite the global one. You can then pass that in as the third parameter to `FormatDateTime`.

Comment: OP passed in a variable that didn't exist, probably confusing the two. In the screenshot, they had something that worked but that was only English. So, this is the solution.

Comment: The question asks about a compilation error. Can you explain where that compilation error is.

Comment: The call to `FormatDateTime` that passes `vDate` is inside a method whose argument is named `vDate`.

Comment: I think the OP had it in Timer1Timer, and that's why it wasn't working. It's implied by the comment "And when I use FormatDateTime('dddd, dd mmmm yyyy', Now); then..." and that line of code is in the timer event. The line in Tanggal() is fine.

Comment: My point is that, in my view, we need to teach the asker to ask the right question. There's just no point at all posting fake code.

Comment: Well... I agree, but I think it was a decent first attempt at a question. He/she posted the working code and they problem they had when they modified it, and how they modified it, and the goal they were trying to achieve. I was surprised by the down votes because both the goal and problem were quite clear, and some effort had been put in to write the question. For a brand new user that's good enough for me.

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason for hardcoding the month names when you can get them direct form Windows:

First make a **proceudre** to setup the month names and call it from **FormCreate**

```
procedure SetupMonthDayNames;
var
  I, Day: Integer;
const
  IndonesianLCID = 1057;

begin
  for I := 1 to 12 do
  begin
    ShortMonthNames[I] := GetLocaleStr(IndonesianLCID,  LOCALE_SABBREVMONTHNAME1 + I - 1, ShortMonthNames[I]);
    LongMonthNames[I] := GetLocaleStr(IndonesianLCID,  LOCALE_SMONTHNAME1 + I - 1, LongMonthNames[I]);
  end;

  for I := 1 to 7 do
  begin
    Day := (I + 5) mod 7;
    ShortDayNames[I] := GetLocaleStr(IndonesianLCID,  LOCALE_SABBREVDAYNAME1 + Day, ShortDayNames[I]);
    LongDayNames[I] := GetLocaleStr(IndonesianLCID,  LOCALE_SDAYNAME1 + Day, LongDayNames[I]);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SetupMonthDayNames;
end;
```

Then you can just update the Statusbar from you timer:

```
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Statusbar1.Panels[0].Text := FormatDateTime('dddd, dd mmmm yyyy', Now);
end;
```

And it will be in indonesian.

Comment: Good point. I should have thought of this in my answer. Why not edit it in?